# Did I just create a real animated .JPG file?

Tags: html, image, animation, jpeg, animated-gif

It all started with this GIF image I found online: https://media.giphy.com/media/9fbYYzdf6BbQA/giphy.gif

I downloaded it to my computer, which runs Windows 10, put it on my desktop, and edited the file name to change ".gif" to ".jpg." The conversion ended up working fine, and I opened the image saved to my computer in my internet browser, Opera, just to see if it would still animate. It opened a file:// URL, and it showed the jpg normally, animating like a GIF would. So, I decided to see if other people saw the JPG animating like a gif, and on a forum site I am an admin for, I uploaded the image as an attachment to a thread. I made the thread, this was the image file I now had, basically just a normal JPG but animated: s4224.storage.proboards.com/5644224/t/crq4LpxP3rTT6eTORg1o.jpg

When I opened the image in Firefox, and got info on the image, Firefox still thought it was a gif in one area showing the file type, though. Internet Explorer said nothing about it being a GIF when I opened the image in that browser. I then saved the page as a JPG, uploaded it to vgy.me, and still got a .JPG result: vgy.me/dX1KGD.jpg

So, have I created a normal, animated .JPG image? Or is it still just a .GIF file that tricks internet browsers? I remember while I was inspecting the image in Opera that it showed the file/image type as "image/jpeg" as well. Seems to be keeping that metadata!

Comment: If your actual question is whether that’s a JPG file that is animated, the answer is: obviously no. It’s definitely a GIF file which just has the JPG extension. If your question is why its type is displayed as `image/jpeg`, I can’t answer that, but that would probably be too broad for a question.

Comment: @Xufox Thank you, that does make sense. The browser was basically fooled by the file extension change. The answer Alohci gave explained it all well too, thank you to him for that. No wonder Firefox still said that the image was actually a GIF.

Answer (score 2):

If you serve a file with a .jpg extension, web servers will normally serve that with a media type of `image/jpeg`, hence that what will get reported in the browser.

But in practice, image files have very different formats, and it's easy for browsers to inspect the file data itself to decide whether it's a JPG or GIF file and process it accordingly. The process that browsers use for doing this is defined in the [MIME Sniffing Standard](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/), which includes the [MIME sniffing in an image context](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#image-type-pattern-matching-algorithm) algorithm.

So, as Xufox says in their comment, it's still a GIF file regardless of its extension.

Answer (score 0):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-photos-winpc/living-images-in-windows-10-photo-app/15736942-9fa7-48eb-bfd4-2152acb582ce

"If you copy the file to a computer and then change the extension to .zip, and open the zip file, you will be able to see the separate jpeg and MP4 files inside.  This is what you were asking I assume?"